# Why do Schottky diodes have three pins

Tags: diodes, schottky

I don't understand how to deal with a Schottky diode that has three pins is it two diodes and work as two or two that work as one? And if I want to use it as a rectifier would I need only two three pin Schottky diodes or four as usual? 
for example if I want to use this diode: [MBR2545CT](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88675/mbr25xxct.pdf) as a rectifier how many of this one do I need? And if you could please show me some schematics I'll be greatful.

Comment: Look at the datasheet. First page. It shows what the three pins are internally connected to. It's two diodes in one package. Done.

Comment: so for a bridge rectifier i need only two ?

Comment: I trust that if you know what a bridge rectifier is, you can answer that question by drawing the schematic of one, and then circling in where you see your MBR2545CTs. You don't need us to do that!

Comment: I don’t know where you are from but the English language starts sentences with capital letter and ends with either period, question mark or exclamation mark with no space before. I is capitalized.

Comment: Marcus Müller I'm hust asking to make sure. i know it needs two

Comment: I would seriously go and check that what you believe is actually true.

Comment: I am sorry i didn't write a clear answer .what i ment with two is one as a common cathode and one as a common anode but i've searched and it looks like there is no common anode schottky diodes so i will need three two separated diodes

Answer (score -2):

Based on correction from JonRB correction

- D1 and D3 **can constitute** one IC
- D2 and D4 has to be **separate diodes**.
- This IC cannot be used alone. Have to go for two more separate diodes or another IC with common anode configuration for D2 and D4.

---

---

[image][image]

Comment: Wrong. the package for MBR25xx is common-Cathode. This isn't flexible enough to produce a full rectifier. At best one could be used for D1 & D3 as this pair share a common cathode connection

Comment: to your edit. You equally cannot use them in series as the package is common-cathode.

Comment: @JonRB I over looked. Thank you

Comment: thanks for your help . my problem is that i can't find separated diodes with a current rating of 25a

Comment: then you're not looking in the right places. typical sources for electronic components are rs-components, mouser, digikey, farnell,…